# How do i store data seperately for each member

Tags: discord.js

So , I wanna make a discord bot which calculates our study time and adda the study time
And makes a leaderboard out of it and some more things , but my problem here is that I want it to store seperate data for each member
For example :
If I type login it should start a stopwatch and when I type logout it should store the time I studied and same goes for the other members

Please help me with this , I gotta make it as soon as possible

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So the stopwatch for individual guild members starts when they type `!login` (ex bot prefix: `!`), and it stops when the members manually type `!logout`. Is that what you mean? Besides, do you have any code on your work yet? If you do, please provide them as well.

Comment: Hey bobosky ,  i don't have much experience in coding . But you got the point . Please help me thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information you provided I assume something like this could be viable:

```js
  let userStartTimes = [];
  //...

  if(command == "login") {
    // only add element if it doesnt exist already
    if(!userStartTimes.some(el => el.id == message.author.id)) {
      userStartTimes.add({id: message.author.id, time: Date.now()});
    }
  }
  if(command == "logout") {
    let index = userStarTimes.findIndex(el => el.id == message.author.id);
    // check if user has logged in before
    if(index != -1) {
      let msecSpent = Date.now() - userStartTimes[index].time;
      // add to leaderboard
    }
  }
```